# Google Play Apps in Samsung App Store

Tags: android, google-play, samsung-smart-tv

I googled around and tried to find out something about the new Samsung App Store. I built an App for `Google Play` and I wonder if I can deploy it to the `Samsung App Store`.

The Android SDK isn't specially built for Google Play I guess. But looking at the Samsung SDK docs it seems quite different from the standard SDK.

Does anybody has any experience with Samsung or knows a link where I can find more info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play is a non exclusive app store. You are free to distribute your app via other channels, such as Amazon App Store, Samsung App Store, emailing apks and even direct downloads from your own site.

Any app that has been written with the Android SDK *should* work on any device running the supported versions Android (assuming the OEM has a bug free and AOSP based ROM).

Keep in mind though that some devices that have the Samsung App Store may not have Google Play and may not be able to use Google Services like In App billing and licensing.

Comment: Well, its not guaranteed that Google Services would work on Nexus or other AOSP based ROMs too. Users could at anytime uninstall Google Play APK. Google themselves recommend app developers have a run time check. An app conforming to that should be fine. Besides, i'm sure Samsung at some point would have the corresponding S services to help such apps work without any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned with Samsung Apps, they take huge fees, there are many intermediaries (agents, commissionaires). While in Google Play you get 70% of the sales, in Samsung Apps you barely get 30-35%... And you are paid 6 months later.